# I need to make something like OkCupids' was of calculating the match percentage in python/web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I want to make something like that, but much more simple. I am using web2py and python.

For example:
I make two profiles for two individuals. For each one I want them to be able to choose 10 movies they like. After that, it compares the movies and output the percentage of similarity.

Again, something like how OkCupid makes you answer questions, and then compares you answers to someone else and give you how much your answers matches theirs.

I am a beginner and need help. If not at least what to look into and study to learn. But a bast generic example would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The best introduction to this area that I have seen is [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do) by Toby Segaran. There is a section in the introductory chapter on 'Finding similar users' that does exactly what you are intending, and it is even in Python.

If you want to play with a recommendation system (*a user likes these ten movies, which other movies might she also like?*), then you may want to try the [python-recsys library](http://ocelma.net/software/python-recsys/build/html/index.html) which has an example using [the movielens dataset](http://www.movielens.org/login).

Finally, welcome to SO and a recommendation for best participation in this community: try to come back with specific code-related questions, something along the lines of: "I have such-and-such a coding problem. This is what I have tried, can you help me move it further?"